# Error while trying to execute an Oracle Stored Procedure from CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I'm working with CodeIgniter and have to modify a SP call

This is working

```
$this->DBTEST = $this->load->database("oracletest", TRUE);
try {
    $params = array(
            array('name' => 'P_DNI', 'value' => $param_dni, 'type' => SQLT_CHR, 'length' => -1)
    );
    $stmt = oci_parse($this->DBTEST->conn_id, "BEGIN MYPROC(:P_DNI); END;");
    foreach ($params as $p) {
            oci_bind_by_name($stmt, $p['name'], $p['value'], $p['length']);
    }
    $res_SP = ociexecute($stmt);
    return $res_SP;
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    return false;
}
```

But when modifying the SP CALL with this, doesn't work

```
$stmt = oci_parse($this->DBTEST->conn_id, "BEGIN MYPROC(:P_DNI,TO_DATE('01/01/2024','dd/mm/yyyy')); END;");
```

**The error output (not very helpful) is**

> Severity: Warning   Message:
> ociexecute():XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> Filename: model_oracle.php   Line number: 69

The mod was tested on console, etc. and works as intended, but not when calling this way through codeigniter

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion

Comment: What error or unexpected behaviour occurs? "Doesn't work" tells us pretty much nothing useful about the problem

Comment: What happens if you change the date format to `mm/dd/yyyy'` in SP call? Does it still error out?

Comment: @ADyson edited the question to output the error I've got

Comment: @Adi nothing, same output

Comment: All those XXX ...they are really part of the error? Or did you redact something?

Comment: @ADyson yes, php outputs all those XXXX, now with oci_error I could get this "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" but don't know why to_date is causing that

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert, but you should likely [edit] your question to show the full error message in case someone can help you. And maybe show more about the SQL side of your code than the PHP